Is there a quicker way to draw a symmetric, scale-invariant (declining color) gradient around an ellipse?
The goal is to generate a picture like this:

A symmetric color gradient around an ellipse which is rotated by $\theta$, has $(x_\circ,y_\circ)$ as center and and major and an minor axis $a,b$.
The total line width should be invariant to changes in those parameters.
It was done by using the implicit ellipse equation with different axis offsets $h$ from $-d$ to $d$ with step size of 1 pixel. So total line width is $2d$.
$$L_{h} = A_{h}x^2 + B_{h}xy + C_{h}y^2 + D_{h}x + E_{h}y + F_{h} = 0$$
with
$$  A_{h} =   (a+h)^2 \sin^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \cos^2\theta $$
$$  B_{h} =  2\left((b+h)^2 - (a+h)^2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta $$
$$  C_{h} =   (a+h)^2 \cos^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \sin^2\theta $$
$$  D_{h} = -2A_{h} x_\circ   -  B_{h} y_\circ $$
$$  E_{h} = - B_{h} x_\circ   - 2C_{h} y_\circ $$
$$  F_{h} =   A_{h} x_\circ^2 +  B_{h} x_\circ y_\circ + C_{h} y_\circ^2 - (a+h)^2 (b+h)^2 $$
We first check if $L_0$ is below (means inside the ellipse) or greater (means outside the ellipse) than $0$. If greater we check if $L_d$ is greater or smaller $0$. If smaller we check it with $h = \frac{d}{2}$. If it is smaller than this we check it for $h = \frac{d}{4}$. If bigger we check for $h = \frac{d}{2} + \frac{d}{4}$.
And so on.
With this we can compute an approximation of the distance with the step size as unit. (note: this is not the shortest point to ellipse edge distance even for very small steps but it's very close to) 
This requires $O(\log_2(d))$ checks per pixel.
Calculating the real distance seems to be require an equation solver for each pixel or solving a quatric equation (degree of 4) with results of thousands of operations.

Can we do any quicker?
For example applying a filter on a ellipse without gradient. How would the math about it look like?
Or can we approximate the distance?
Or something else?

More details:
Will be used for many ellipses with different arbitrary parameter $\theta, (x_\circ,y_\circ), a ,b$.
My related math stack threads: about inner and outer boundary, about distance point to ellipse, about quick calculation of gradient

You can exactly find the distance to a 2D ellipse using the signed distance function of an ellipse. Here is one by iq on shadertoy:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sS3zz
Then a scale invariant way of generating the gradient can be achieved by adding before the last fragColor statement in mainImage():
col = vec3(0.0);
float gradientWidth = 0.1;
if(abs(d) < gradientWidth) {
    //col = vec3(1.0) * (1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, abs(d) / gradientWidth)); //use this for smooth gradient
    col = vec3(1.0) * (1.0 - (abs(d) / gradientWidth));
}


wow, what a nice page. And wow that there is actually an analytic solution. Thousand times faster to solutions I found but still using some slow trigonometry and root functions. However there are also links to approximative solutions not using any trigonometry. (Points need to be rotated by $\theta$ and translated by $x_\circ,y_\circ$).
Will need to test which is actually the fastest. Will mark this as answer. Thank you! If someone posts some faster/better way (e.g. some filter?) I can change it again.
